# multiple Android Support library v4

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, facebook-android-sdk, viewpagerindicator, android-support-library

I have a project which is using three external libraries: ActionSherlock, ViewPagerIndicator and FacebookSDK 3.x

All of them need the android support library but the problem is that if i link every library to the androidsupportv4.jar (even if it's the same) eclipse fails in exporting the apk giving back the dalvik error 1 (which usually appears when you're trying to put the same .jar multiple times).

How can I solve this without having to copy the libraries into my project? (I'd like to avoid this so to have just one library for all my projects...it's easier to update the library for everyone!)

Thank you in advance!

Comment: How do you link the projects to the support-library? It has to be in the libs folder of every project, not only in the Build Path.